# Mapping multiple Array in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mapping

I am trying to achieve this :
[image: To achieve]

While trying, I created an JavaScript Object(JSON like object) to access it. Here's the code:

```js
const weekArray = [
  {
    weekMonth: 'February',
    weekDayofWeek: ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur'],
    weekDays: [ '04', '11', '18', '25'],
    weekStatus: 'Available +',
    className: 'February'
  },
  
  {
    weekMonth: 'March',
    weekDayofWeek: ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur'],
    weekDays: [ '04', '11', '18', '25'],
    weekStatus: 'Available +',
    className: 'March'
  },
  
  {
    weekMonth: 'April',
    weekDayofWeek: ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur'],
    weekDays: [ '01', '08', '15', '22', '29' ],
    weekStatus: 'Available +',
    className: 'April'
  },
  
  {
    weekMonth: 'May',
    weekDayofWeek: ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur'],
    weekDays: [ '06', '13', '20', '27' ],
    weekStatus: 'Available +',
    className: 'May'
  }
];

const WeekShow = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      {weekArray.map((weekValues) => (
        <div key={weekValues.className}>
          <span>{weekValues.weekMonth}</span>
          <div className="card">
            <h5>{weekValues.weekDayofWeek}</h5>
            <h5>{weekValues.weekDays}</h5>
            <h5>{weekValues.weekStatus}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <WeekShow />,
  root
);
```

```css
span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Now, I'm trying to access each data in object file to get the desired result showed in the image but it's not working well.
Don't mind the styles, I  just want to focus on the main objective.
What could be the error? Please check and help!

Comment: I've noticed that the data structure that you are using is not able to handle different status for different weeks. Is it okay to reshape it? It will also change the way of rendering (which will become easier)

Comment: Yes, you can. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest to change a shape of `weekArray` so it's easier to render and can handle different statuses per each week.

At fist dimension it will have months (as it is right now). I suggest for each month to have `week` array with data for each week.

```js
const monthsArray = [
    {
        month: 'February',
        className: 'February',
        weeks: [
            {
                day: '04',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '11',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '18',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '25',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        month: 'March',
        className: 'March',
        weeks: [
            {
                day: '04',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '11',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '18',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '25',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        month: 'April',
        className: 'April',
        weeks: [
            {
                day: '01',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '08',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Not Available',
            },
            {
                day: '15',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '22',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '28',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        month: 'May',
        className: 'May',
        weeks: [
            {
                day: '06',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '13',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
            {
                day: '20',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Not Available',
            },
            {
                day: '27',
                dayofWeek: 'Thur',
                status: 'Available +',
            },
        ]
    },
];

const WeekShow = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        {monthsArray.map((monthValues) => (
                            <div key={monthValues.month}>
                                <span>{monthValues.month}</span>
                                {monthValues.weeks.map((weekValues) => (
                                    <div key={weekValues.day} className="card">
                                        <h5>{weekValues.dayofWeek}</h5>
                                        <h5>{weekValues.day}</h5>
                                        <h5>{weekValues.status}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <WeekShow />,
    root
);
```

```css
span {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop `.weekDayofWeek` once again :)

```
const renderWeekDayofWeek = ({weekDayofWeek, weekDays, weekStatus}) => {
  return weekDayofWeek.map((r, index) => (
    <div className="card" key={index}>
    <h5>{r}</h5>
    <h5>{weekDays[index]}</h5>
    <h5>{weekStatus}</h5>
  </div>
));
}
```

Call the `renderWeekDayofWeek()` like below:

```
 {weekArray.map((weekValues) => (
      <div key={weekValues.className}>
        <span>{weekValues.weekMonth}</span>
        {renderWeekDayofWeek(weekValues)}
      </div>
    ))}
```

```js
const weekArray = [
  {
    weekMonth: 'February',
    weekDayofWeek: ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur'],
    weekDays: [ '04', '11', '18', '25'],
    weekStatus: 'Available +',
    className: 'February'
  },
  
  {
    weekMonth: 'March',
    weekDayofWeek: ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur'],
    weekDays: [ '04', '11', '18', '25'],
    weekStatus: 'Available +',
    className: 'March'
  },
  
  {
    weekMonth: 'April',
    weekDayofWeek: ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur'],
    weekDays: [ '01', '08', '15', '22', '29' ],
    weekStatus: 'Available +',
    className: 'April'
  },
  
  {
    weekMonth: 'May',
    weekDayofWeek: ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur', 'Thur'],
    weekDays: [ '06', '13', '20', '27' ],
    weekStatus: 'Available +',
    className: 'May'
  }
];
const renderWeekDayofWeek = ({weekDayofWeek, weekDays, weekStatus}) => {
    return weekDayofWeek.map((r, index) => (
      <div className="card" key={index}>
      <h5>{r}</h5>
      <h5>{weekDays[index]}</h5>
      <h5>{weekStatus}</h5>
    </div>
    ));
  }

  const WeekShow = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        {weekArray.map((weekValues) => (
          <div key={weekValues.className}>
            <span>{weekValues.weekMonth}</span>
            {renderWeekDayofWeek(weekValues)}
          </div>
        ))}
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  

ReactDOM.render(
  <WeekShow />,
  root
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```